# Android Matrix isn't displaying properly, how do I fix it?

Tags: android, canvas, matrix

XML is not the factor in this case. I'm overriding the canvas with the onDraw function and providing the entire screen as a canvas.

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

```
    int gemID=0;
    for(int c=0;c<5;c++){
        for(int r=0;r<5;r++){
            gemID= GemField[c][r];
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmps.get(gemID),c,r,null);
        }
    }
```

Upon creating the canvas to draw on I create the matrix, and then I fill the matrix as seen in the following bits of code.

private void createGemField() {

```
    Random rnd= new Random();
    for(int col=0;col<5;col++){
        for(int row=0;row<5;row++){
            int gemNum = rnd.nextInt(4-0);
            GemField[col][row]=gemNum;
        }
    }
```

}

```
private void drawGems(){
    int gemID=0;

    for(int col=0;col<5;col++){
        for(int row=0;row<5;row++){

            gemID=GemField[col][row];
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmps.get(gemID),col,row,null);

        }
    }

}
```

Unfortunately the image I get is square in the top left of the screen with multiple objects that seem like they're scaled over each other. More like a snakes scale or shingles, the objects overlap but not completely. The further from the starting place holder in the matrix the less they overlap. Any idea why this may be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`canvas.drawBitmap(bmps.get(gemID),c,r,null);`

Here, `c` and `r` are the x and y components of the point on the canvas where the bitmap is drawn. I assume your bitmaps are larger than 1px, so you should change this into:

`canvas.drawBitmap(bmps.get(gemID), 50 * c, 50 * r, null);` or something like this; between the bitmaps is now 50px space.

Comment: Omg thank you so much. I can't believe I didn't notice that, well you fixed my problem.

Comment: Ok cool i am glad i could help :-) Could you accept this as an answer?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to do that. I got it now though.